# Copying Stream from XmlTextWriter to a FileStream

Tags: .net, vb.net, stream

I have an HTTP Handler that is binding an `XmlTextWriter` instance to `Response.Output` like so...

```
Sub GenerateXml(ByRef Response As HttpWebResponse)
    Using Writer As New XmlTextWriter(Response.Output)
        ' Build XML
    End Using
End Sub
```

And now I also want the same XML to be saved to the local hard drive (in addition to being streamed to the response).  How can I do it?

**Things I have tried**

1) The obvious, copying the Response.OutputStream to a new FileStream...

```
    Sub GenerateXml(ByRef Response As HttpWebResponse)
        Using Writer As New XmlTextWriter(Response.Output)
            Build XML Here
        End Using

        // Also tried this inside the Using, with and without .Flush()
        CopyStream(Response.OutputStream, File.Create("C:\test.xml"))
    End Sub

    Sub CopyStream(ByRef Input As Stream, ByRef Output As Stream)
        Dim Buffer(1024) As Byte
        Dim Read As Integer

        Using Input
            Using Output
                While (Read = Input.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)) > 0
                    Output.Write(Buffer, 0, Read)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

I get errors like "Method not supported" and "NullReference"

2)  Using a Memory Stream and then copying it...

```
    Using Memory As New MemoryStream()
        Using Writer As New XmlTextWriter(Memory, Encoding.UTF8)
            Build XML Here
        End Using

        // Tried outside of the Using, with and without Flush()
        CopyStream(Memory, Response.OutputStream)
        CopyStream(Memory, File.Create("C:\test.xml"))
    End Using
```

I get errors like "Cannot access a closed Stream."

Why is something so simple such a PITA?!

Comment: Do I really have to resort to writing the file to disk and then using `Response.TransmitFile()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't wire up `Response.OutputStream` in that manner. However, you could do one of two things:

1. Create a method that calls `Stream.Write` for both your test file and `Response.OutputStream`.

   ```
   using (var writerResponse = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream))
   using (var writerFile = new XmlTextWriter(File.Create(@"c:\test.xml"))
   {
       StartElement(writerResponse, writerFile, @"test");
   }
   ```
2. Create a wrapper class which encapsulates two streams to be written to and provides all of the stream methods you require (`Write` etc).

   ```
   public class DualStream : Stream
   {
       public DualStream(Stream first, Stream second)
       {
       }

       public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }
       public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }

       public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
       {
           this.first.Write(buffer, offset, count);
           this.second.Write(buffer, offset, count);
       }
   }

   // ...

   using (var writerFile = new XmlTextWriter(File.Create(@"c:\test.xml")))
   using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(
         new DualStream(Response.OutputStream, writerFile)), null))
   {
        // use writer
   }
   ```

Comment: Sigh, I was hoping for something easier but I guess this will do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the memorystream position to 0.

i.e.:

```
Memory.Position = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the save method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save%28VS.71%29.aspx

I don't know if you will be able to use it in your context.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this EchoStream class on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/echostream.aspx) by googling for `.net stream tee` (tee being the unix-y word for what you want).